# Div container to expand with dynamic grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

this is kind of a two parter. I have a dynamic grid composed of divs (.unit) that I'm trying to contain in one larger div (#pallet). The grid increases based on the integer the user gives in a prompt. My question is how do I get the larger div to expand relative to the size of my grid without using absolute positioning? Also the grid isn't ever reduced to the user given value, it only increases. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  var userChoice = 10;

  for(var x = 0; x < userChoice; x++) {  
    for(var y = 0; y < userChoice; y++) { 
       var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>"); 
       unit.appendTo('#pallet'); //puts div "unit" into div "pallet" using appendTo
    }
  }

   $(".unit").hover(function(){   //jquery selects the "unit" div and issues a function on it to change the css 
   $(this).css("background-color", "black");   //this is in reference to .unit changing the css to black

  });


  document.getElementById("reset").onclick = gridReset;    //reset is the id of our button, so when it's clicked it will call our function gridReset


   function gridReset() {    //function grid reset first asks a prompt then stores the user's choice value in a variable and puts it through checks to see if its valid


   userChoice = prompt("Between 1 and 64 how big would you like your grid?");  //we put our user choice in the function so as to not call a prompt at the start of the page load AND to store the variable in the scope


   if (isNaN(userChoice)) {

    alert(userChoice + " is not a number");

   }
   else if (userChoice >= 65 || userChoice <= 0) {

    alert("Choose a number between 1 and 64");

   }

   else { 

     $(".unit").empty();        
     $(".unit").css("background-color", "blue");

     for(var x = 0; x < userChoice; x++) {  //for loop creates iteration of userChoice
     for(var y = 0; y < userChoice; y++) { //for loop creates iteration of userChoice

     var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>"); //creates a variable "unit" = to a jquery div element with a class of unit 

     unit.appendTo('#pallet'); //puts div "unit" into div "pallet" using appendTo

      $(".unit").hover(function(){   //jquery selects the "unit" div and issues a function on it to change the css 

      $(this).css("background-color", "black");   //this is in reference to 
.unit changing the css to black

    });


   }

  }
 }
}

  });
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
  <title>Odin Div Project</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" />
</head> 

<body>
  <button id="reset" type="button">Reset Grid</button>
  <div id="pallet">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#pallet {
  position: relative;
  left: 425px;
  top: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 440px;
  width: 440px;

}
.unit {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Also the grid isn't ever reduced to the user given value, it only increases`?

Comment: once prompted if the user submits an integer, the userchoice value doesn't reduce the grid past it's initial 10. I assumed it would with the (".unit").empty block but the divs remain